# how to trigger sqoop actions using oozie

Tags: hdfs, oozie, hortonworks-data-platform

I am trying to launch sqoop action from oozie and have tried by myself as well as asked questions on forums. I keep getting the same error.

```
job.properties:

nameNode=hdfs://FQDN:8020
jobTracker=FQDN:8050
queueName=default
user.name=oozie
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.action.sharelib.for.sqoop=hive,hcatalog,sqoop
oozie.action.sharelib.for.hive = hive,hcatalog,sqoop
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/scheduledimport
start=2016-04-26T00:00Z
end=2016-12-31T00:00Z
workflowAppUri=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/scheduledimport
```

I am launching oozie jobs from oozie user only.

My worflow is nothing but a simple list table command:Apart from this I have all the default configs in oozie-site.xml.

I have checked and share/lib/lib_timestamp folder exists in /user/oozie

```
<workflow-app name="once-a-day" xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
        <start to="sqoopAction"/>
        <action name="sqoopAction">
                <sqoop xmlns="uri:oozie:sqoop-action:0.2">
                        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                    <command>list-tables --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
 --connect jdbc:mysql://FQDN/erp --username hive --password hive
                    </command>
                </sqoop>
                <ok to="end"/>
                <error to="killJob"/>
        </action>
        <kill name="killJob">
            <message>"Killed job due to error: ${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}"</message>
        </kill>
        <end name="end" />
</workflow-app>
```

oozie admin -oozie http://FQDN:11000/oozie/ -shareliblist outputs:

```
[Available ShareLib] 
hive 
mapreduce-streaming
oozie 
sqoop
pig
```

I have also tried adding the configurations inline in workflow.xml

Also, have checked that my oozie-site.xml has

```
<property>
      <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
      <value>/user/oozie/share/lib</value>
    </property>
```

which is where I have the dependencies.

Which jar file has `org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain`?
But I keep getting this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain not found
```

I have made sure that folder with jar files has required set of permissions and access to user. Tried updating share/lib folder. Made sure the folder has sqoop related dependencies but it won't work.

Comment: whats the error, you are getting?

Comment: @NishuTayal: Please check the update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following may be the root cause of this `ClassNotFoundException`  :

1. Either Sqoop jars are not available in the sharelib directory
2. `oozie.use.system.libpath` is not set to true.

In your case, you are already setting **oozie.use.system.libpath=true**

Make sure, sharelib directory has the sqoop dependency.

And following property should be set in oozie-site.xml(in case if default sharelib path is not used):

```
   <property>
    <name>oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath</name>
    <value>/user/oozie/share/lib</value>
  </property>
```

And while submitting the workflow, use correct job.properties.

```
$ oozie job -oozie http://localhost:11000/oozie -config job.properties -run
```

I also faced the similar issue, but setting `oozie.use.system.libpath=true` resolved it.

Here is the [Oozie sharelib documentation](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/)

Comment: The property to be set in oozie-site.xml, I have that added through ambari interface already.In custom oozie-site: oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath: /user/oozie/share/lib. When you say in case default sharelib is not used, is user/oozie/share/lib not default? That's all that I have. Also, you say it happends when sqoop jars are not available, as my shareliblist command shows, sqoop jars are available but yet I am facing the issue

Answer (score 1):

The class apache.oozie.action.hadoop.SqoopMain is part of mysql-connector-java-*.jar. You need to download it and add to Oozie library.